# Applying conditional formatting to variable range

Tags: excel, vba

I want this macro to select range C6:N6, apply a format condition, step 7 and so on until the end of my list.
When i execute it, it bings me an error regarding the objects.

I think my problem is on the following part:

```
For i = 6 To lastRow Step 7
    Range(C & i, N & i).Select
```

This way I want to make the ranges variable.
Below is my code:

```
Sub test1()
' Coluna C

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Pega ultima celula com valores na coluna C

For i = 6 To lastRow Step 7
    Range(C & i, N & i).Select 'what am i missing?

         With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
        Formula1:="=0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is considering both `C` and `N` as variables, when it should consider them as literals. For that you need to enclose them in double quotes(`"`). Try to replace them to `Range("C" & i, "N" & i).Select`. And why not working with the entire range at once, instead? you could remove the `For` and just work with something like `Range("C6", "N" & lastRow).Select`

Comment: How did I not see that? Hehe. Works great, thank you!

Comment: @VictorMoraes - actually, I suggest Serveira [avoid `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) completely. It will save many headaches in the future. (But I agree with your overall point to work with the range at once).

Comment: @BruceWayne I completely agree with you and I'm actually working on some code to add a proper answer to this post, without using the `Select`, though I understand that OP is not working with entire range, since he is using `Step 7` in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of keeping this into comments, here is an answer to your problem.
Your code is considering both `C` and `N` as variables, when it should consider them as literals. For that, you need to enclose them in double quotes(`"`). So instead of

```
Range(C & i, N & i).Select
```

You need to do

```
Range("C" & i, "N" & i).Select
```

There is also one problem with your `lastRow` assignment. Based on your comments you want to get the last cell with values from column `C`, which is column `3`, but you are passing the wrong index for colum in here:

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Pega ultima celula com valores na coluna C
```

Instead, you should be using

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ' <-- column C is index 3
```

I'm adding this because you might find issues if your column `A` is not properly filled or doesn't have the same amount of data as the desired column `C`

Besides, as greatly suggested by [BruceWayne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517087/applying-conditional-formatting-to-variable-range#comment66350322_39517087) (off topic: nice username, by the way), you should [avoid `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) completely in your code. You can work with `With` blocks, similarly to what you are already doing, and also use proper reference to your cells and ranges, instead of relying on the active worksheet. With that, you would end up with a code more like the following

```
Sub test1()
' Coluna C

    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row ' Pega ultima celula com valores na coluna C

        For i = 6 To lastRow Step 7
            With .Range("C" & i, "N" & i)

                With .Interior
                    .Pattern = xlNone
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
                    Formula1:="=0"
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 255
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
            End With

        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks great, thank you! As it's been only one week since i started leaning to code, it's kind of inevitable for me to use `.Select`, it looks so much easier, ahah. As i see, it's best to avoid it completely from the beggining, so I'll have a detailed look at your code and see how it is improved from mine. Many thanks!